# React Custom Built Navbar

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom Navigation menu that I want to use for a website in react that I am creating, I want the Nav Links to move out when the Navigation Menu is clicked.

There are a few parts that I will automatically assume are incorrect like where I am passing the props.

A side note I use styled components in this project, so anything with with style in its name is related to styled components, also the main reason I want components seperate by using navItem is so that I can manipulate them in different ways with CSS.

I thought it would be best to link all the files I am working with starting with the Navlink: -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavItemStyle from "./NavItemStyle";

class NavItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavItemStyle>
        <ul onClick={this.props.click}>
          <li value={this.props.nav}>
          </li>
          <li value={this.props.children}>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </NavItemStyle>
    );
  }
}
export default NavItem;
```

This is the  NavItems section, I am assuming this is completely wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import NavItem from './NavItem/NavItem';

class NavItems extends Component {

  render() {

    return this.props.navlists.map((navItem) => {
      return <NavItem
          click={() => this.props.clicked}
        />
    });
  }
}
export default NavItems;
```

This is the main navigation component that will be linked in App.

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import NavMenu from "./NavMenu/NavMenu";
import NavItem from './NavLists/NavItem/NavItem';
import NavStyle from './NavStyle';

class Navigation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMenu: false
    }
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({showMenu: !this.state.showMenu})
  }
  render() {


  return (
    <NavStyle>
      <NavMenu/>
      {/*Nav items Display Home and Things to do.*/}
      <NavItem />
      <NavItem />
    </NavStyle>
  );
}
}


export default Navigation;
```

Also to save pasting loads of lines of code I put the NavMenu(Burger) on a paste bin here: - https://pastebin.com/T671GBjF

The end result I am hoping is when the burger is pressed the Links to the page show.

Comment: What is not working? Can you share? I can assume that the click is not working, as you need to pass the function, without creating new function. In NavItems change the click to click={this.props.clicked}

Comment: I can share the repo if it helps? aside from the actual custom nav created in CSS and Svg nothing else works.

Comment: Please share what you expect from the code and it is not working..

Comment: I want the burger menu to display items when its clicked, so lets say a profile page: Home, About, Etc thats the first step so it will for now default and move out to the left side.

Comment: Can you share the repo? I am missing some code and I am not sure how exactly it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're not passing the props correctly. Actually, you're not passing them at all.

In order to use a prop in a child component, you need to pass them from the parent. So, on the navigation class you would need to do something like:

```
<NavItem click={this.handleClick} nav={this.somethingItsNotClearForMe}>
   This text would be props.children on the NavItem
</NavItem>
```

I guess you need to get this logic of passing props from parent to child before going any further

Comment: With the Nav section how would I go about this then assigning it with state so that it displays the name?

Comment: You can do something like 
<NavItem click={this.handleClick} name="Name of item" />
and on the child 
<li onClick={this.props.click}>{this.props.name}</li>